# Wrong opencart product images when I try to share on facebook

Tags: php, html, facebook, opencart

It's my online store http://goo.gl/1AJpjN (opencart 1.5.5.1)
The challenge is to share the homepage on facebook properly and the product pages as well.

There was no problem with product pages. The addthis.com extension worked quite well, I could see product images with proper title and descriptions on fb... but there was no fb share button for homepage.

So, I added fb share button for homepage in blue horizontal menu using fb normal HTML 5 code from here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/

After I did it there is no problem with homepage sharing. Fb shows store logo and proper title with proper description, but when I try to share product pages, fb shows store logo instead of product images.

As I said, The challenge is to share the homepage on facebook properly and the product pages as well.
What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you share a page on Facebook, Facebook crawls it and tries to decide which image it should use. If it's showing the wrong one, you can help it by adding a meta tag to the page specifically for this issue. You can find [more information here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags).

An example would be

`<meta name="og:image" content="http://www2.intelnet.ge/image/cache/data/uploads/32438HP_PAVILION_TOUCHSMART_11_E100SR__F5B63EA___0_7b_enl-500x500.jpg">`

Adding this to your `<head>` using OpenCart's templating system can be a bit convoluted, however there are already quite a few extensions that do this. I'd suggest [having a look here](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension&filter_search=facebook%20open%20graph).

Comment: Of course, I try this way. I added this code in header.tpl file. But with no result.

Comment: this si the code I added, but in this case, fb show store logo for product pages instead of product images <meta property="og:description" content="description text here!" />  
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www2.intelnet.ge/image/logo.jpg" />

Comment: Be aware that Facebook caches its crawling results. You can reset their data here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Just try - fb show store logo for product pages instead of product images

Comment: I don't understand. You said you have set the image meta tag to your logo, so yes, that's what it's going to use. If you want it to show your product image, you need to set it to your product image.

Comment: I need logo for homepage only and product images for product pages. Is it possible? I can't set product image meta tag for 10 000 product.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but I don't have time to mod Opencart for you. You better have a look at the extensions I linked to!

Comment: Tried all modes. None of them can do what I need.

Comment: The first 3 do EXACTLY what you have asked for.