# Opencart dynamic OG meta tag

Tags: php, facebook, share, opencart

my site http://goo.gl/aWQnd9

Opencart 1.5.5.1

I use this codes for dynamically get properly product images

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $thumb; ?>"/>
```

or

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo _GET['image] ?>"/>
```

or

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?= $_GET['image'] ?>" />
```

But with no result. Every time Fb shows store logo and proper title with proper description, but when I try to share product pages via addthis.com extension, fb shows store logo instead of product images.

What to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrong opencart product images when I try to share on facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491228/wrong-opencart-product-images-when-i-try-to-share-on-facebook)

Comment: I have tested and it works, it shows the product image instead of the logo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your theme header.tpl add:

```
<!-- mod og:image para FB -->
<?php if ($thumb || $images) { ?>
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $thumb; ?>">
<?php } else { ?>
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $logo; ?>">
<?php } ?>
<!-- mod og:image para FB -->
```

In controller/common/header.php, just after: $this->data['name'] = $this->config->get('config_name'); add:

```
if (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
         $product_id = (int)$this->request->get['product_id'];
      } else {
         $product_id = 0;
      }

      $this->load->model('catalog/product');
      $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);      
      $this->data['product_info'] = $product_info;
      if ($product_info['image']) {
            $this->data['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product_info['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_thumb_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_thumb_height'));
         } else {
            $this->data['thumb'] = '';
         }         
         $this->data['images'] = array();
```

Answer (score 1):

You do more than one query in the method mentioned above. Not a good idea for performance.

Try the codes I wrote below

**open the file *system/library.document.php***

***private $scripts = array();* after**

```
private $metas = array();
```

***function name: getLinks()* after**

```
public function addMeta($keyword, $value) {
    $this->metas[$keyword] = array(
        'keyword' => $keyword,
        'value' => $value
    );
}

public function getMeta() {
    return $this->metas;
}
```

**open the file *catalog/controller/header.php* and find the *$this->document->getStyles()* after**

```
$data['metas'] = $this->document->getMeta();
```

**open the file *catalog/view/theme/YOURTHEME/template/common/header.twig* and find the *{% for link in links %}* before**

```
{% for meta in metas %}
    <meta property="{{ meta.keyword }}" content="{{ meta.value }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

and one last operation

**open the file *catalog/product/product.php* and find the *$this->document->setTitle($product_info['meta_title'])* before**

```
 $this->document->addMeta("tiwtter", $product_info['meta_title']);
```

and it's okay.

Have a good day.